# Automatic lock not working

Tags: honda, locks, door

2001 Honda CRV, when lock button is pressed rear PS door lock sounds like a machine gun (ra-ta-ta-tat) and door remains unlocked. Door cannot be manually locked either, what could be causing this?  Is it likely to be the actuator gone bad, or just a mechanical jam up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you cannot manually lock the door, the power locks will not work because all it does is move the mechanical linkage. This sounds like the linkage or latch (the lock mechanism is in the latch) is binding on something. Take the door panel off and inspect the linkage and latch. You may have to take the latch out of the door to inspect it close enough.

Comment: I hope that's the case, it will save me ~$120.00 if I don't have to buy a new actuator.

Comment: @tester101 it's possible that the binding has stripped the gear inside the actuator so you may still need that, but you have to get the linkage moving first before you will be able to tell that

Comment: Turns out the assembly that the actuator interacted with was rusted causing it to be unmovable, a bit of liquid wrench solved the problem.